# Angular data-bs-datepicker directive + on date change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, date, datepicker

So I have a list of tasks.
Each task has a planned start date and a planned end date (plannedStartDate / plannedEndDate). I use ng-repeat to create my table.
I need a simple anchor which on click triggers a datepicker AND:

- has the start date set to the plannedStartDate of the task (it is never null)
- is bound to the plannedEndDate of the task, as in, whenever a value is selected, I have to somehow catch this event so I can update the DB value (plannedEndDate) of the task.
- I have to show the date in format: dd/mm/yyyy

BUT:

- both the plannedStartDate and plannedEndDate have this format: 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000

Currently, my datepicker looks like:

```
         <a href="#" data-bs-datepicker
               data-date-startDate="task.plannedStartDate" data-ng-model="task.plannedEndDate"
               data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy"
               data-date-type="string">
                {{task | dateIndication}}
            </a>
```

I've tried with and without the date-format and date-type, but neither seem to help me. Also, the start date is automatically set to TODAY if I use this, even though the plannedStartDate of the task is not today. (I'm guessing it's a date formatting issue?)

I have tried putting a watch on the tasks array:

```
$scope.$watch('tasks', function (newVal) { /*...*/ }, true);
```

(and with a few more variations like using watch collection etc), but nothing!

The change is simply not caught.

(also, the dateIndication filter looks like:

```
 .filter('dateIndication', function () {
        return function (task) {
            if (task.plannedEndDate) {
                var plannedEndDate = moment(task.plannedEndDate);
                return plannedEndDate.format('L');
            } else {
                return messages.dashboard.todosAndTasks.noDueDate();
            }
        }
    })
```

I would very much need some help. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using a pure JS Date object  in task.plannedEndDate model?

Comment: I managed to catch the change event on the .plannedEndDate, but not as I wanted. I am catching the change event on the whole collection and have to iterate through it to see what exactly changed.
But now the problem with the plannedStartDate as a 'low-limit' for the date picker remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var change;

change = function(date) {
           var r;
           r = date.match(/^\s*([0-9]+)\s*-\s*([0-9]+)\s*-\s*([0-9]+)(.*)$/);
           return r[2] + "-" + r[3] + "-" + r[1] + r[4];
 };
```

use this function and pass the date when function is call it will return the perfect format for datepicker and it shows perfectly fine and one more thing u need to split the date before passing the date then it works fine check it out and tell me what is diffrent

Comment: No, this doesn't work. I tried adding your code to the formatter/filter but still nothing

Comment: create a sample on jsfiddle and send the link let  me check